# #[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, windows, nodemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfsL3.png)

I'm facing a problem where my Node.js application crashes without displaying any specific error message. When I try to run my project in VSCode, it only shows [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..., but there's no additional error information.

Here's what I've already tried:

Checking Terminal Output: I've looked for error messages in the terminal output, but there's nothing other than the message about the app crashing.

Disabling Nodemon: I attempted to run the application without Nodemon to see if the issue persists, but the problem remained.

Verifying Node.js Version Compatibility: I made sure that my Node.js version is compatible with my project dependencies to rule out any version-related issues.

Reviewing VSCode Extensions: I checked for any VSCode extensions or configurations that might be causing the problem, but disabling them didn't resolve the issue.

Inspecting VSCode Configuration: I reviewed my VSCode settings and configurations to see if anything could be interfering with the project execution, but I couldn't find any obvious issues.

Updating Dependencies: I ensured that all project dependencies, including VSCode extensions, are up-to-date to eliminate the possibility of outdated dependencies causing the problem.

Consulting Community Forums: I haven't reached out to community forums yet, but I'm considering seeking assistance there if I can't resolve the issue on my own.

I'm still unable to determine why my Node.js application is crashing in VSCode without providing any error message. Any further guidance on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest debugging your code. Use the built-in debugger in Node.js or a tool like node-inspector to step through your code and find where it's crashing.